# Probing Dlls through Reflection in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, reflection

I have been trying to find more information on the technique of  dll and exe discovery by way of writing programs using ASP .Net and reflection(?).  I haven't been able to find anything.

I know there are dissassemblers but I am not interested in running other tools and disassembling code per say, I am more interested in understanding how to write  a program that takes an unknown file or executable and determines the properties and methods within that are public.

I am just starting on my search for this and was wondering of any good resources to jumpstart the learning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am more interested in understanding how to write a program that takes an unknown file or executable and determines the properties and methods within that are public.

Reflection is a good way to do that. Here are a few tips if you don't want a full code explanation.

1. You could use the [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx) to load an existing assembly. This will only work for .NET assemblies. The difference between `Load` and `ReflectionOnlyLoad` is that `Load` loads an assembly that allows you to use it, like executing a method on a type in that assembly. `ReflectionOnlyLoad` is useful when you only want to look at what is in the assembly without executing any code. The other advantage of `ReflectionOnlyLoad` is that it doesn't care what platform the assembly was compiled for.
2. Once you have the assembly, you can use a method like [`GetExportedTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes.aspx) to get a list of all of the public types. If you want to get the public and non-public, you can use just `GetTypes`().
3. So now we have our assembly loaded, and a list of all of the types. The [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class has several members for working with that type. GetMethods and GetProperties come to mind.

You can refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) MSDN article for a more general overview of Reflection.

Comment: This is a good start for me.  Does this mean that if I want to discover other dlls that may not have been written in .net that I would need to use another language.  Would c++ be a better choice for writing an unknown dll prober.  In your opinion, which would be the best language to choose and which methods would be best to leverage for a dll prober that is flexible?

Comment: @byten .NET stores all of it's information much differently than a native binary. If you wanted to know more about DLLs that were not written for .NET I'd start learning the [PE File Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)